# How to get outlet params from ActivatedRoute (Angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript, router, outlet

My routes are defined as:

```
    path: 'geooperations',
    component: GeoMetricsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':idgeooperationmetrictype', component: DetailGeoMetricTypeComponent, outlet: 'geo' },
      { path: ':idgeooperationmetrictype/edit', component: DetailGeoMetricTypeComponent, outlet: 'geo' },
      { path: '/new', component: DetailGeoMetricTypeComponent, outlet: 'geo' }
    ]
```

**Example:** 
URL: geooperations/(geo:c56da64c-0ef5-4894-83ee-043818b44e14)

```
outlet : 'geo'
idgeooperationmetrictype: 'c56da64c-0ef5-4894-83ee-043818b44e14'
```

How do I can get the 'idgeooperationmetrictype' from the ActivatedRoute ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the snapshot.params :

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.subscribe(params => {           
   console.log(params['idgeooperationmetrictype']);
});
```

Comment: `snapshot.params` is not and have never been an Observable.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to subscribe to it inside the component "DetailGeoMetricTypeComponent"

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = params['idgeooperationmetrictype'];
    });
  }
```

Or set breakpoint with dev tools at the params line to see the keys.

Comment: The first answer did not work. However, I can get the 'idgeooperationmetrictype' by this.activatedRoute.url._value[0].path. I don't know if this is OK or there is another way to do it via outlet params ?

Comment: `activatedRoute.snapshot.params` did the Trick.